# Passing selected ComboBox indices to an array VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, combobox, userform

I have a question, which I hope you can answer.
I'm trying to programm a UserForm which contains 19 ComboBoxes all with the same value (names of employees) for a shift schedule. There are 5 entries in each ComboBox (5 employees). So far so good.
What I'm trying now is, to pass the selected indices (0, 1, 2, 3, 4) to an array upon clicking a button in the userform. At the end I should have an array with 19 entries (for each combobox).
My problem now is, that I don't know if the indices were passed succesfully to my array "Larray". Below is the code

```
Public Sub cmd_Erstellen_Click()

Dim j As Long
Dim Larray As Variant

For j = 1 To 19

Me.Controls("ComboBox" & j).ListIndex = Larray

Next j



Unload UserForm1


End Sub
```

Comment: (1) Assignations need to be the other way round (2) if you reversed that line your code would be assigning 19 values to the same variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you want this?

```
Public Sub cmd_Erstellen_Click()

Dim j As Long
Dim Larray(1 To 19) As Variant

For j = 1 To 19
    Larray(j) = Me.Controls("ComboBox" & j).ListIndex
    Debug.Print j & ", " & Larray(j) 'show result in immediate window
Next j

Unload UserForm1

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way, please:

```
Public Sub cmd_Erstellen_Click()
 Dim j As Long, Larray(18) As Variant

 For j = 1 To 19
    Larray(j - 1) = Me.Controls("ComboBox" & j).ListIndex
 Next j
 Debug.Print Join(Larry, ",") 'it returns the array as string in Immediate Window
                              'only to see if it is what you expect...

 Unload UserForm1
End Sub
```